# More efficient way of using dataframe.loc to call info from one dataframe to another

Tags: python

I wonder if you can propose a more efficient way of doing this?

I have two dataframes as follows: 
1) One dataframe with the location of various "stations":

```
   StationNames   Lat          Long
0   St1         1.30405        103.77350
1   H2          1.30414        103.77355
2   H11         1.30446        103.77375
```

2) a dataframe with timestamps of when I was at different stations:

```
               Description        Session       Survey
Local           
2018-10-06 09:48:30   St1       Oct06_Morning   Survey
2018-10-06 09:56:30   St1       Oct06_Morning   Survey
2018-10-06 09:58:30   H2        Oct06_Morning   NoSurvey
```

Now I want to add a column to the second one, which depending on the station name (Description), it get the address (Lat,Long). 
I made a loop but sounds inefficient. Any suggestions? 
Thanks, 
Negin

```py
TimeStamps['Lat']=0.00
TimeStamps['Lng']=0.00
for i in range(TimeStamps.shape[0]):
    ALong=StationAddress.loc[StationAddress.StationNames==TimeStamps.Description[i],'Long']
    Blat=StationAddress.loc[StationAddress.StationNames==TimeStamps.Description[i],'Lat']
    #print i, ALong, Blat
    TimeStamps['Lng'][i]=ALong
    TimeStamps['Lat'][i]=Blat
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [merge()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html) function.

So if your frames are:

```
StationAddress = pd.DataFrame(data=[['St1',1.30405, 103.77350], ['H2',1.30414, 103.77355],['H11',1.30446, 103.77355]], 
               columns=['StationNames', 'Lat','Long'])

TimeStamps = pd.DataFrame(data=[['2018-10-0609:48:30','St1','Oct06_Morning', 'Survey'], ['2018-10-06 09:56:30','St1','Oct06_Morning', 'Survey'],['2018-10-06 09:58:30','H2','Oct06_Morning', 'NoSurvey']], 
               columns=['local','Description', 'Session','Survey'])
```

Try this:

```
TimeStamps.merge(StationAddress, 
                               left_on='Description', right_on='StationNames',  
                                how='left', left_index=True).set_index('local')
```